# TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined | but users is defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, expo

I'm having this error now and I dont know why.

[image]

I get that the line of error is in this code, but I don't see what I did wrong.

```
const found = getState().usersState.users.some(el => el.uid === uid);
```

The Code :

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE, USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants/index";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore'

export function fetchUser(){
    return ((dispatch) =>{
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) =>{
                if(snapshot.exists){
                    dispatch({type: USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: snapshot.data})
                }else{
                    console.log('does not exist')
            }
        })
    })
}

export function fetchUserPosts(){
    return ((dispatch) =>{
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .orderBy("creation", "asc")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) =>{
                let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return{id, ...data}
           })
           dispatch({type: USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts})
        })
    })
}

export function fetchUserFollowing(){
    return ((dispatch) =>{
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("following")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection("userFollowing")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>{
                let following = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return id
           })
           dispatch({type: USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE, following})
           for(let i = 0; i < following.length; i++){
                dispatch(fetchUsersData(following[i]));
           }
        })
    })
}


export function fetchUsersData(uid) {
    return ((dispatch, getState) => {
        const found = getState().usersState.users.some(el => el.uid === uid);
        if (!found) {
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection("users")
                .doc(uid)
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    if (snapshot.exists) {
                        let user = snapshot.data();
                        user.uid = snapshot.id;

                        dispatch({ type: USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE, user });
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('does not exist')
                    }
                })
                if(getPosts){
                    dispatch(fetchUsersFollowingPosts(uid));
                }
        }
    })
}

export function fetchUsersFollowingPosts(uid) {
    return ((dispatch, getState) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(uid)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .orderBy("creation", "asc")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                const uid = snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[1];
                const user = getState().usersState.users.find(el => el.uid === uid);


                let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data, user }
                })

                for(let i = 0; i< posts.length; i++){
                    dispatch(fetchUsersFollowingLikes(uid, posts[i].id))
                }
                dispatch({ type: USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts, uid })

            })
    })
}
```

This is what I have in the folder reducers:

index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { user } from './user'
import { users } from './users'


const Reducers = combineReducers({
    userState: user,
    userState: users
})

export default Reducers
```

user.js:

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants"

const initialState = {
    currentUser: null,
    posts: [],
    follwing: [],
}

export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: action.currentUser
            }
        case USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            }

        case USER_FOLLOWING_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                following: action.following
            }
            default:
                return state
    }
    
}
```

users.js:

```
import { USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants"

const initialState = {
    users: null,
    userLoaded: 0,
}

export const users = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: [...state.users, action.users]
            }
        case USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                usersLoaded: state.userLoaded + 1,
                users: state.users.map(user => user.uid === action.uid ?{...user, posts: action.posts} :
                user)      
            }

        
            default:
                return state
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please show your reducer

Comment: You have to provide your reducer before someone can help because `user` state is defined in your reducer.

Comment: @Viet uploaded it, hope it helps!

Comment: @Delice Hope this will help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
const found = getState().usersState.users.some(el => el.uid === uid);
```

here `users` are coming from a async request and that is not available on first render. So you have to put a check like:

```
if( getState().usersState && getState().usersState.users )  // Access it when it is available
{
  const found = getState().usersState.users.some(el => el.uid === uid);
}
```

or

```
const found = ( getState().usersState && getState().usersState.users ) ? getState().usersState.users.some(el => el.uid === uid): [];
```

something like this. Try this and error will be gone and you will get the data.

Comment: Thanks, @Mayank! I had to use yours and Viets his and now it's working ! Thanks!

Comment: Please extract `getState().usersState` to a variable. This is too much for me to handle

Comment: @Delice right, its good to store that in a variable and use that variable on all the places where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe firebase is still fetching the user, you can use optional chaining `?` to protect this kind of behavior. try this

```js
const found = getState().usersState?.users?.some(el => el.uid === uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote wrong in the `combineReducers`. `usersState` instead of `userState`

```
const Reducers = combineReducers({
    userState: user,
    usersState: users
})
```

Comment: ... or he mispelled his state :D

Comment: @Delice it's she haha

Comment: @Viet this helped but I somehow had to combine your answer with Mayank his and then it worked! Thanks! :)